# How to I alter a string like 'santa maria' into "Santa Maria'?

Tags: java

My program is working but not in the manner I want.  This is the output I want:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Joe King\My Documents\418.85A Java\Projects\Day 6>java Project3 nina pinta "santa maria"



The Nina is decreasing throttle!

    The Nina is ready to launch...

            but the throttle is down, increase throttle!


The Pinta is lowering the main!

    The Pinta is ready to launch...

            but the sail is down, hoist the main!


The Santa Maria is hoisting the main!

    The Santa Maria is ready to launch...

            the sail is up, ahead full!



(press ENTER to exit)
```

As you can see, Santa Maria has been capitalized.  Here is the output I get:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Joe King\My Documents\418.85A Java\Projects\Day 6>java Project3 nina pinta "santa maria"



The Nina is decreasing throttle!

    The Nina is ready to launch...

            but the throttle is down, increase throttle!


The Pinta is lowering the main!

    The Pinta is ready to launch...

            but the sail is down, hoist the main!


The santa maria is hoisting the main!

    The santa maria is ready to launch...

            the sail is up, ahead full!



(press ENTER to exit)
```

My code is failing to capitalize names strings like Santa Maria.  Here is my code:

```
class Project3{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Boat[] boatArray;
    String result = " "; 
    char firstChar;
    char firstLetter;
    char secondLetter;
    int i;

    boatArray = new Boat[args.length];

    if(args.length > 0){

        for(i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++){

            String delimiters = "[ ]";
            int limit = -1;

            String[]tokens = args[i].split(delimiters, limit);

            for( int k = 0 ; k < tokens.length ; ++k ){

                if( tokens[k].length() > 1 ){

                    tokens[k] = tokens[k].trim();

                }else{

                    tokens[k] = " ";

                }

                firstChar = tokens[k].charAt(0);

                if(firstChar == ' '){

                    break;

                }else{

                    if(Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)){

                        break;

                    }else{

                        firstChar = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
                        char[] tokenArray = tokens[k].toCharArray();                            
                        String text = new String(tokenArray, 1, (tokenArray.length - 1) );                          
                        tokens[k] = firstChar + text;

                    }

                    result = result + tokens[k];

                    if( k != tokens.length - 1 ){

                        break;

                    }else{

                        result = result.trim();
                        args[i] = result;
                        result = " ";

                    }
                }
            }       

            firstLetter = args[i].charAt(0);

            if((firstLetter == 'B') || (firstLetter == 'C') || (firstLetter == 'N')){

                boatArray[i] = new RaceBoat();
                boatArray[i].christenBoat(args[i]);

            }else{

                boatArray[i] = new SailBoat();
                boatArray[i].christenBoat(args[i]);

            }


        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        for(i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++){         

            secondLetter = Character.toUpperCase(args[i].charAt(1));

            if((secondLetter == 'A') || (secondLetter == 'E')){

                boatArray[i].increaseSpeed();
                boatArray[i].goFast();

            }else{

                boatArray[i].decreaseSpeed();
                boatArray[i].goSlow();

            }           

            boatArray[i].launchBoat();
            boatArray[i].whatIsBoatState();

        }

    }else{

        System.out.println("\n\nArgh!... you forgot to enter ship names scalawag!" +
            "\n\n\n\tPlease try again!");

    }

    System.out.println("\n\n(press ENTER to exit)\n\n");

    try{

        System.in.read();

    } catch(IOException e){

        return;
    }
}
```

}

The thought the problem may be that parsing santa maria caused the following:

```
' santa '

' '

' maria '
```

I thought this code would trim it:

```
if( tokens[k].length() > 1 ){

                    tokens[k] = tokens[k].trim();

                }else{

                    tokens[k] = " ";

                }
```

but apparently it doesn't.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kristopher!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Commons-Lang `StringUtils.capitalize` function.

[Capizalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

You have available the source code which can be useful if you want to learn how the pro's make it :)

And this may capitalize your word.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
String[] parts = originalWord.split(" ");
for(String part : parts) {
    String capitalized = part.substring(0, 1).toUppercase() + part.substring(1);
    b.append(capitalized).append(" ");
}
//and then you can remove the last space if it is your taste.
return b.toString();
```

It lacks basic checks but it would do :).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response Juan, I will try to use this code!

Comment: I've added a simple and incomplete but functional example if you'd like to make it work. My piece of advice as a professional programmer is "keep it simple" if you require lots of lines of code for a simple task, then you're either overkilling or not thinking it well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again for your help, hope I can be professional as well someday soon.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought this code would trim it ...

Actually, that code will also replace any one-letter word with a space.

Another problem is with the regex you are using.  You want to treat one OR MORE spaces as a SINGLE delimiter.  Refer to the javadocs and / or your text book and lecture notes on how to write a regex to do that.  (Note: if you get this right, there won't be any need to trim whitespace.  Split will do it for you.)

Enough hints :-)

---

> I thought about that as well, yet most boat names don't have single letters in English.

You shouldn't hard-wire assumptions like that into your code.  Especially when you don't NEED to.  Hard-wired assumptions lead to fragile code; i.e. code that breaks when your assumptions turn out to be incorrect [sometimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Robert_E._Lee_%28SSBN-601%29).

Comment: I thought about that as well, yet most boat names don't have single letters in English.  I know in Spanish you could use 'y' as an example but as you can see this isn't production worthy :).  On second thought an 'A' could be used so something else to think about!  Thank you for your hints, I will look into it!

Comment: Of course you were absolutely right!  Thanks, I removed the code!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are using break; at many places, this will terminate the loop so following words will not be processed at all. Probably you want to skip current word/arg only so you should use continue which will continue the for loop with next index.

You can use debugger or add some intermediate printf statements to understand the code flow better.

Comment: I removed the break statements and replaced them with continue.  Thank you!